# Pandas: clustering data using Markov chains

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe

```
member_id   domain
111     vk.com
111     facebook.com
111     stackoverflow.com
222     facebook.com
222     twitter.com
333     wikipedia.org
333     vk.com
333     facebook.com
```

I need to clustering ID and I need to get Markov chains from domain path, but I have some difficulties.

```
111: vk.com -> facebook.com -> stackoverflow.com
222: facebook.com -> twitter.com
333: wikipedia.org -> vk.com -> facebook.com
```

Should I create adjacency matrix to every id? And if I do that is any way to clustering that? Or there are another way?
Or I should get all path and compare with it every id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you'll want to do something with your Markov chain after aggregating it, you might want to represent it as a python list, for example...

```
outer_list = []
for ID, sites in old_df.groupby("ID"):
    inner_list = sites["domain"].values.tolist()
    outer_list.append(inner_list)

IDs = old_df.ID.unique()
new_df = pd.DataFrame()
new_df["member_id"] = pd.Series(IDs).values
new_df["chain"] = pd.Series(outer_list).values
```

you'll have a dataframe that looks something like this...

```
member_id   chain
0   1   [vk, fb, so]
1   2   [fb, tw]
2   3   [wik, vk, fb]
```

disclaimer: not the fastest, most pythonic code blah blah...

Answer (score 3):

```
df.groupby('member_id')['domain'].agg(' -> '.join)
```

Output:

```
member_id
111    vk.com -> facebook.com -> stackoverflow.com
222                    facebook.com -> twitter.com
333        wikipedia.org -> vk.com -> facebook.com
Name: domain, dtype: object
```

Or as a list:

```
df.groupby('member_id')['domain'].agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Output:

```
member_id
111    [vk.com, facebook.com, stackoverflow.com]
222                  [facebook.com, twitter.com]
333        [wikipedia.org, vk.com, facebook.com]
dtype: object
```